# USe of filereaderasarraybuffer but it read only textfile not read image,excel file so what to do?

Tags: javascript

USe of filereaderasarraybuffer in javascript but it read textfile ,read image,excel file but content of image,excel file is not displayed so how to use it properly??

Answer (score 0):

As an answer:

`filereaderasarraybuffer` is not a known function in Javascript... or any language?